# Can speech recognition be done in ML.NET?

Tags: speech-recognition, ml.net

I am new to Machine Learning. I came across ML.NET (Machine Learning framework by Microsoft). Can we use this framework for speech recognition? What all things you should know if you want to do a speech recognition in ML.NET?

Comment: ML.NET does not process audio at this point, just text and images. You can ask for it in the ML.NET github page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMHO, for beginners, modifying sample neural networks/deep learning solutions is a good start point. And, for neural networks the start point is Tensorflow. With ML.net you can consume Tensorflow models.

Audio recognition with Tensorflow:

https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/sequences/audio_recognition

A sample for using Tensorflow models with ML.net:

https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning-samples/tree/master/samples/csharp/getting-started/DeepLearning_ImageClassification_TensorFlow

Comment: Thanks Cihan Yakar for suggestion. Will try this.

Comment:  @KashyapNeeraj

Comment: Can you share exsample of using wave instead image?